# Matrix bracket notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I am reading a section in a book that talks about normal matrices, and I see the following:

```
A normal matrix is a matrix that commutes with its adjoint,
```

[image: huh?]

Eh? What do the brackets and the comma inside mean?

Answer (score 8):

The notation means that $AA^{T}-A^{T}A$=0.

Comment: It is called the commutator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory